# pyinstaller: No module named 'numpy.distutils'

Tags: numpy, scipy, pyinstaller

I am trying to package my python application for other users that dont have python installed. I use `pyinstaller`.

My application has multiple dependencies which I e.g. import via `import numpy as`

So far I have tried:

```
pyinstaller --paths venv\Lib\site-packages --onefile Main.py
```

The packaging runs without errors. But when trying to open the .exe file I get:

```
(venv) PROJECT_DIR>dist\Main.exe

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from LinearProgram import LinearProgram
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "LinearProgram.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scipy.optimize
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 401, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "scipy\optimize\_constraints.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "numpy\testing\_private\extbuild.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
[3812] Failed to execute script 'Main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have verified that the application is working when running `python Main.Py`

I also tried installing the missing pakachges manually with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import numpy --hidden-import scipy --hidden-import matplotlib Main.py
```

This leads to the exact same error.

I also tried it with `--hidden-import numpy.distutils` which also didnt work.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to package all my dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue (windows, python 3.9, pyinstaller 4.7, numpy 1.22).
pyinstaller 4.7 is not compatible with numpy 1.22.

Short term solution : downgrade numpy to 1.21.5.

Long term solution : waiting for pyinstaller update (hook numpy)

You can submit this bug to
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs

Hope that will be helpful.